# Blocking the [quantum] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The tag [quantum](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum) keeps cropping up on the site (you won't see any question with it now because I remove it every time it happens, but every so often someone adds it when asking a question).

To me, this seems an obvious case of a tag that we should blacklist. I'm creating this post [following the procedures in place for this sort of thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/276202). If anyone has any reason to be against this, please speak now, or forever hold your peace. Otherwise, this seems uncontroversial enough an issue to just contact the CMs to blacklist the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [quantum](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum) tag has entered the [quantum realm](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Quantum_Realm), never to return again! It has been added to the site's blocklist as an intrinsic tag.

Users attempting to use the [quantum](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum) tag will now receive the message:

> The 'quantum' tag is not allowed.

Comment: thank you! Should the [tag:status-planned] tag be changed to status-completed or such?

Comment: Oops yes, thanks :)